# a local hello world flask app behind a reverse ssh tunnel isn't reachable through internet

Tags: ssh

the hello world example of the flask is run on my laptop on port 5000 and host 0.0.0.0.
I create a reverse ssh tunnel with :
`ssh -R 5000:localhost:5000 usr@my-vps-ip`
the  `curl localhost:5000` on my VPS will return the expected result.
I expect that `curl my-vps-ip:5000` must also return the expected result too, but I get
`Failed to connect to my-vps-ip 5000: Connection refused`. stoping the firewall isn't solved the problem.
I tested this with ngrok, and that is working.
I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes. there are the same questions. But it did not solve my problem.

Comment: So please [edit] your question and state you tried `-R :5000:localhost:5000` and checked the state of `GatewayPorts` option on the SSH server.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I the things you asked.

Comment: After changing to `clientspecified`, did you restart the SSH server or otherwise tell it to reload the configuration?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski i do that now, and problem is solved. tankyou man.

Comment: I restored your original question. I will improve my answer to the other question, so it states one needs to reload the configuration.